# Расшифровка команды cat **/c*

Tags: unix, terminal, solaris

Помогите расшифровать команду. Я понимаю, что cat выводит файлы, `c*` это маска для файлов, начинающихся на 'c', но что значит `**/`?

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, вы можете принять его, отметив галочкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это так называемый `globstar` - рекурсивный поиск во всех поддиректориях. Т. е. этот код выведет все файлы, начинающиеся на `c`, из всех директорий уровнем ниже данной.

С одной звёздочкой команда была бы ограничена только поддиректориями текущей папки (т.е. `abc/catalog`, но не `abc/cde/country`).

Но для работы этой опции нужно её включить соответствующей командой:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
```

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option

Answer (score -1):

насчет 2-х звездочек перебор. А так, одна, любой подкаталог в текущем каталоге, в нем файлы начинающиеся с "C"